# как сделать что бы главная страница открывалась сразу?

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

есть простенький сайт-портфолио, все залила на pythonanywhere, все работает!

но, когда перехожу по прямой ссылке - то есть, http://****.pythonanywhere.com/ пишет ошибку 404, когда добавляю /projects - то все отлично, как и должно быть.

как мне сделать что бы работало напрямую, без переходов?

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что ваш сайт расположен в папке `/home/myusername/mysite/projects`

Если это так, то следует переместить его на уровень выше, то есть `/home/myusername/mysite`, возможно даже в `/home/myusername`

Comment: нет, папка с проектом - documents/Папка/ПапкаСПроектом

Comment: имеется в виду на хостинге pythonanywhere. Какой путь до main.py?

Comment: /home/юзер/юзер.pythonanywhere.com/manage.py

Comment: В таком случае надо смотреть ваш urlpatterns

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("projects/", include("projects.urls")),
 у меня там это

Comment: А во views какие вьюхи есть?

Comment: def project_index(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {"projects": projects}
    return render(request, "project_index.html", context)


def project_detail(request, pk):
    project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {"project": project}
    return render(request, "project_detail.html", context)

Comment: замените path("projects/", include("projects.urls") на path("/", include("projects.urls")

Comment: AttributeError at /

'tuple' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://aniri20020.pythonanywhere.com/
Django Version:  2.2.28
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  

'tuple' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Exception Location:  /home/usr/.virtualenvs/usr.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in resolve, line 542
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi

Comment: написало(( ошибка

Comment: А если добавить from projects.views import project_index и заменить паттерны

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", project_index, name="project_index"),]